# Insert referenced variable into RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, url, request-mapping

Hi I'm forcing with problem connected to @RequestMapping. I'm trying to insert variable into URL from another class and make range in regular expression. Could you tell me if it's possible?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v{:[1-currentVersion]}/dictionary")
```

Another Class With currentVersion value

```
public static int currentVersion = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't do this in such way, because annotations doesn't support non-constant attribute values. Only if `currentVersion` can be `final` - it will work:

```
public final static int currentVersion = 1;
// ...
@RequestMapping(value = "/v{:[1-"+currentVersion+"]}/dictionary")
```

Furthermore, from general point of view, request mapping it self is quite static thing. If you have some dynamically changing values, you can only check them inside your method body.